# Is it possible to pass the reference to the i-th element of a primitive array?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, primitive

Right now, somewhere in my code, I am passing a reference to a primitive, for example an `Int`

```
val i = 0
```

to

```
fun whatever(i: KMutableProperty0<Int>)
```

as

```
whatever(::i)
```

to being able to get/set its value from within the function

Everything worked great so far.

I'd like now to do the same for an i-th element of a primitive array, such as an `IntArray`

```
val arr = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)

whatever(/* passing the reference to item 2 of arr*/)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What about passing the reference to the `arr` property and the index?

```
fun whatever(arr: KMutableProperty0<IntArray>, index: Int)

whatever(::arr, i)
```

Comment: Because at that point I can pass the array itself, no need the reference

Comment: You could pass Int directly in your first example as well, so I thought there's a reason you're passing KMutableProperty0<Int> instead.

Comment: No, because if `whatever()` would change its value, I couldn't see it anymore once `whatever()` has returned. Think about like `&i` in c++

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, since Java doesn't allow pointer operations on arrays. Kotlin doing that (if possible at all at the bytecode level) would break interoperability.

**EDIT**: It seems you don't care about *true* array pointers, like in C, so you can create yourself wrappers similar to those `KMutableProperty`:

```
class IntArrayRef(val array: IntArray, val index: Int) {
    fun get(): Int = array.get(index)
    fun set(value: Int) { array[index] = value }
}

fun modify(value: IntArrayRef) {
    value.set(4)
}

fun test() {
    val s = "abc"
    val arr = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
    modify(IntArrayRef(arr, 1))
}
```

My guess is you would need to create manually one wrapper for each native array type, since [they are exposed at the Kotlin level as non generic types](http://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.1/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Arrays.kt#L94).

Comment: But why should it break the interop? Java does not support field references either (`::someField`), but Kotlin can wrap such into a `KProperty` and pass it to a Java method that accepts it. I believe, this is not the reason why this feature does not exist.

Comment: @hotkey, would it make sense open an issue on youtrack for a future potential implementation?

Comment: @hotkey a KProperty is just a generic wrapper object you can create yourself too, see edit. My understanding of array references/pointers is much more lower level and efficient than that, you would need to change the jvm to implement them like in C languages.